# Other classes using the psychic warrior list?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

The war mind uses the psychic warrior power list. (And so does the psychic warrior, of course.) Does anything else? Ideally I’d like to find something using that list but based on Charisma, but for this question I’d like a complete list of all manifesting classes that use the psychic warrior list.

Any and all WotC and WotC-licensed 3.5e material is valid for this, including Mind’s Eye. My overall goal, by the way, is to dip something for access to the list so I can activate *dorjes* or a *psicrown* with a couple of psychic warrior powers (*grip of iron* and *form of doom*). The Charisma-based part is just to get some free bonus power points from the dip (my Wisdom is awful).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Fist of Zuoken (Complete Psionic 43) and Zerth Cenobyte (Expanded Psionics Handbook 144) Prestige Classes, along with the War Mind and of course the Psychic Warrior itself, are the only WotC classes that gain inherent manifesting and use the Psychic Warrior power list. Both those classes use wisdom to determine power points per day. I've found nothing in The Minds Eye, and the 3rd edition [Athas](https://athas.org/) sources don't appear to show any new classes with inherent manifesting from the Psychic Warrior list either.

So the list is four classes long:

1. Psychic Warrior
2. Fist of Zuoken
3. War Mind
4. Zerth Cenobyte

Comment: Officially-licensed Dark Sun support for 3.x is found at [athas.org](https://athas.org), and all of their PDFs are free, if you were looking to get that “access.” They do have new classes, but no classes with their own manifesting from the psywar list. Good call checking them (and checking the actual published _Expanded Psionics Handbook_ instead of just the SRD). +1 for a great answer.

Comment: @KRyan Ah. I'd checked their site, but didn't check to see whether the PDFs had prices... Thanks for the info, I'll amend with your info.